# something like statsd + graphite for Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm new to GAE and though I've looked around a fair bit, I haven't seen anything that mimics the functionality of statsd for GAE.  Basically it would be nice to have something that you could easily set stats on and see the results graphed.

http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/

Answer (score 1):

One thing that seems to be difficult for statsd is handling unlimited amount of data. If you are interested in aggregate application statistics (across the entire dataset), I would suggest using the App Engine Log API or the App Engine Datastore in conjunction with [Google BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/).

If you are interested specifically in analyzing App Engine logs, there are two projects that you can take a look at that helps move App Engine Log data into BigQuery:

- [log2bq](http://code.google.com/p/log2bq/), a Python app for GAE logs->BigQuery
- [Mache](http://blog.streak.com/2012/07/export-your-google-app-engine-logs-to.html), a framework for pushing GAE log data into BigQuery (I know you are
  asking about Python , but this one is written in Java)

For general stats collection and analysis, it's also possible to move Datastore data into BigQuery for analysis. The GAE team has recently started testing a feature that imports data from the experimental Datastore backup tool directly into BigQuery. Check [this link](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dHdpeXlmRlZCNWlYSE9BcE5jc2NYOUE6MQ) for more info.

BigQuery doesn't provide visualization tools on it's own, but there are lots of ways to visualize BigQuery's query results, examples include:

- [Google Chart Tools API](https://developers.google.com/chart/)
- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/bigquery_tutorial?hl=en)
- [Tableau](https://plus.sandbox.google.com/116015649554712337984/posts/CeXBgH2xzPo)
- [QlikView](http://market.qlikview.com/qlikview-connector-for-google-bigquery.html)

There's a lot more on the [BigQuery third party tools](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/third_party_tools) page.

Comment: So it seems there's kind of a gap in the same kind of plug-and-play stats functionality that statsd provides in GAE, right?  Do you think people just don't need this or do they all end up rolling their own using these tools?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really the place for vague architectural questions - the answer depends on what you are trying to build. App Engine's Events Logging and LogService API are mature and well integrated. If you have specific technical questions about how to produce visualizations or aggregate queries from the data collected by these services, I'd add them to your question. (Read more: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logservice/overview and https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/logging).